# jqPlot tick labels: angle and spacing

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Using jqPlot to draw a simple line graph, I cannot find a way to:

(a) Add some spacing between the tick labels on the Y axis, and the tick marks (to me, the string "100" is shown on top of the tick mark, which is bad)

(b) hide the tick values "0" and "2011/12" on the Y and X axes, respectively

(c) have the tick labels on the X axis to show on a 30 degree angle

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4cneh5j/5/

I am setting the tickOptions angle parameter, as follows, but it is not changing anything:

```
tickOptions: {
    angle: -30
}
```

Please feel free to update it or give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add proper javascript

```
   <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.ohlcRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
```